# Binary matrix column subset selection complexity

Tags: np-hardness, combinatorics, boolean-matrix

Given an $m \times n$ matrix ($m$ rows) containing only $0$'s and $1$'s, what is the complexity of finding an $m \times k$ submatrix (of $k$ columns) such that within the chosen submatrix there is no row containing only zeroes, in other words, every row contains at least one $1$?

For example, given the $4 \times 3$ matrix

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
                 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
                 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
                 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

a subset of $k=3$ columns that fails to fulfill this condition is that of the first columns, as the third row has all zeros within this submatrix, but the column set $\{1, 3, 4\}$ would be a solution.

I suspect this is a hard problem, but I haven't been able to find a direct reference. I'm interested in this problem because of its applications in cryptography.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rephrasing as a set system, each row represents a subset $E_i$ of some set $X$, for $i=1,2,\dots,m$.  You want a set $Y \subseteq X$ with at most $k$ elements, such that $E_i \cap Y \ne \emptyset$ for each $i$.  In other words, you want a [hitting set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation) of size at most $k$; this problem is NP-complete.

Answer (score 2):

It is NP-hard, here is a reduction from SAT:

You have variables $x_1,\dots,x_m$, and clauses $C_1,\dots,C_n$ on these variables.

You build the following $(m+n)\times 2m$ matrix:

For $i\in[1,m]$, the $i^{th}$ row contains only $0$ except two $1$'s in column $i$ (representing variable $x_i$) and column $m+i$ (representing $\neg x_i$).

Then, the following $n$ rows are clauses : row $n+j$ contains exactly variables (or negated variables) appearing in clause $C_j$.

There exists a subseteq of columns of size $m$ if and only if the formula is satisfiable.
The first $m$ rows forces to choose for each $i$, either $x_i$ or $\neg x_i$, and the last rows ensures that every clause is satisfied by the chosen valuation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be (m + n) x 2m?

Comment: You probably want to say that this is a reduction _from_ SAT.

Comment: Why do you say that the first $n$ rows forces to choose $x_i$ or $\neg x_i$? One can choose both.

Comment: because your subset of columns has to pick a $1$ in line $i$, and the only ones are those corresponding to $x_i$ and $\neg x_i$, meaning you have to pick one of the two. You cannot pick both, because you are allowed only $m$ columns in total, so it is just enough to choose a valuation. If you choose both, there will be a $j$ such that neither $x_j$ nor $\neg x_j$ is in your subset.

Comment: What about: $x_1 \land \neg x_1 \land (x_2 \lor x_3)$? $m = 3$ but one can pick columns $x_1, \neg x_1, x_2$ and make the formula satisfiable. But perhaps I didn't understand well your reduction.

Comment: There is something wrong with the argument, because you could indeed pick for the first $i < m/2$ variables both $x_i$ and $\neg x_i$ and if every clause contains one of those variables then you have a solution. That is, you make some form of an assumption about the structure of the clauses that is not apparent in the text.

Comment: Your counter-example does not work because the matrix contains lines forcing you to choose $x_2$ or $\neg x_2$, and $x_3$ or $\neg x_3$. This is not forced by the clauses, but by the first $m$ lines.

Comment: @dkuper: ok, I understood it.